# NLog.Web.AspNetCore no longer logging to database

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a dotnet core API that's up on version 2.2 with NLog.Web.AspNetCore 4.7.0 (NLog 4.5.11) which was previously working back in version 4.5.4.  With the update, it now doesn't appear to be logging to the database.  Nothing in terms of the logging infrastructure has changed within my code.

I should mention, I also have in the log this lovely line, so I know it's somewhat working.  But I use to get A LOT more information, and of course, the database would have stuff written to it as well.

```
2018-12-26 15:06:59.9503||DEBUG|SomeApp.API.Program|init main |url: |action:
```

I tried looking around in the github issues and on here, but I haven't found anything of much use, any help is greatly appreciated!

Initial Setup in Program.cs

```
var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
try
{
    logger.Debug("init main");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //NLog: catch setup errors
    logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
}
finally
{
// Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

Implementation

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
                })
                .UseNLog()  // NLog: setup NLog for Dependency injection
                .Build();
```

nlog config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true"
  internalLogLevel="Trace"
  internalLogFile="C:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

 <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
 </extensions>

 <targets async="true">

 <target type="File" name="file" fileName="${basedir}\logs\logfile.txt"
  maxArchiveFiles="5" archiveAboveSize="20971520" archiveEvery="Day"
  layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />

<target xsi:type="Null" name="blackhole" />

<target name="database" xsi:type="Database">


  <connectionString>${gdc:item=connectionString}</connectionString>

  <commandText>
    insert into dbo.Log (
      EventId, Logged, Level, Message,
      Username,
      ServerName, Port, Url, Https,
      ServerAddress, RemoteAddress,
      Logger, CallSite, Exception
    ) values (
      @EventId, @Logged, @Level, @Message,
      @Username,
      @ServerName, @Port, @Url, @Https,
      @ServerAddress, @RemoteAddress,
      @Logger, @Callsite, @Exception
    );
  </commandText>

  <parameter name="@EventId" layout="${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}" />
  <parameter name="@logged" layout="${date}" />
  <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />

  <parameter name="@username" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />

  <parameter name="@serverName" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_NAME}" />
  <parameter name="@port" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT}" />
  <parameter name="@url" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_URL}" />
  <parameter name="@https" layout="${when:inner=1:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' == 'on'}${when:inner=0:when='${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTPS}' != 'on'}" />

  <parameter name="@serverAddress" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=LOCAL_ADDR}" />
  <parameter name="@remoteAddress" layout="${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_ADDR}:${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REMOTE_PORT}" />

  <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
  <parameter name="@callSite" layout="${callsite}" />
  <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
</target>

</targets>

<rules>
<!--Limit to only configured logs for all logs, change name="*"-->
<logger name="SomeApp.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="database" />
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
<!--Skip Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
<logger name="Microsoft.*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="blackhole" final="true" />
</rules>
</nlog>
```

Sample logging code

```
_logger.LogInformation(1001, "Login success: {0}", userForLoginDto.Username);
```

appsettings.json & appsettings.Development.json Logging Settings

```
  "Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Trace",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
}
```

The NLog internal log doesn't seem to have anything of significance, I can provide it if requested though.

Apologies for any weird formatting issues, the nlog.config file did not want to come willingly.

Comment: I would focus on getting the file-logging working first (for more than "init main"), and not focus on the database-target. Looks like `UseNLog` fails to register NLog as LoggerProvider, or that you have activated Microsoft Extension Logging Filtering: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/wiki/Getting-started-with-ASP.NET-Core-2#5-configure-appsettingsjson (Check you don't have environment specific appsettings.json files)

Comment: Added the logging that's configured in both appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json to the main post.  I've tried running the API under development and production, nothing new.  I do use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, as I always have and that used to work.

Comment: If you are able to create a small example solution that reproduces the issue with missing file-logging, then please create an issue here with the example-solution attached: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues

Comment: Done and done, thanks @RolfKristensen https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/331

Comment: Think I figured it out, seems that it doesn't like me splitting up the CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run() into two parts.  I updated the github issue to see if this is a known thing, or why.

Comment: hey there, how do you pass in the connectionstring from the app to the nlog config? having issues with that atm.